# Two Ubuntu versions on the same computer

Tags: dual-boot

Is it possible to install both Ubuntu 12.04LTS and Ubuntu 13.10 on the same computer? I already have 12.04 32bit and just wanna try the new version. I run Ubuntu on Dell Latitude D620.

Comment: I would guess you need to make a partition for each Ubuntu version :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this, you'll run in to kernel management complexity.  It's much easier to try the live version or try the later version in a VM.

If you really MUST have them both installed, I'ld install them on separate disks with grub installs to mbr on both.  Then you can specify which disk each os_prober should search with an edit like [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1412654).

Finally, you can choose which disk to boot at your bios screen.

It keeps the whole process dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible to install two ubuntu versions on the same pc,but you need to have seperate partitions for each version.

Only one swap partition is enough,no need to create swap partition for each version.